# Proof of properties of dual cone

Tags: duality-theorems

Show that if C $\subseteq$ D then $D^*$ $\subseteq$ $C^*$

where * is dual cone operation. Can somebody explain it.

Comment: Depends on what kind of "dual sets" you are talking about, it would seem. I'm guessing you mean dual vector space, but it is hard to tell.

Comment: Define the dual operation please.

Comment: $D^*$ is a dual cone of D and same for C

Comment: It pretty much follows directly from the definition. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

In view of the comment, I imagine that $C$ and $D$ are subsets of some Euclidean space $E$, that $C^*=\{x\in E:(\forall y\in C)\,x\cdot y\geq0\}$, and similarly for $D^*$. If so, and if $C\subseteq D$, then any $x\in D^*$ satisfies $x\cdot y\geq 0$ for all $y\in D$, and that includes all $y\in C$, so $x\in C^*$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $D^*$, that proves $D^*\subseteq C^*$.