# Polar cones' property

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to prove:
$A \subseteq B \implies B^\circ \subseteq A^\circ$ 

where $A^\circ$ is polar cone of $A$ ($A$ convex cone) and
 $B^\circ$ is polar cone of $B$ ($B$ convex cone)

Comment: Ok, solution found :)http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677540/proof-of-properties-of-dual-cone